# invocable_traits

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++20

Update: there are new versions of this code: [v3 is posted here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272710/invocable-traits-v3) and [v4 is posted here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272747/invocable-traits-v4)

---

Goal: implement traits that for anything callable return its arity, return type and the argument types. Since pointers to data members are also callable, those should be handled (and be considered 0-arity).

Code below, [try here](https://godbolt.org/z/oqxb6foh5). This is v2, after comments received [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272633/callable-traits-implementation/272648).
Besides the suggested changes, i have added support for function references, now also provide information about the class the invocable belongs to (if member function, or data member), and provide better error messages if you want try to get the traits on something not callable.
I decided not to put a ref to the class as the first argument type, but instead provide it separately. Testing if class_type is not void tells you if a ref to a class instance is needed. Indeed, for pointers to static member functions, class_type is void.

```
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// derived and extended from https://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/traits.hpp
// and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28213747
// This does not handle overloaded functions (which includes functors with
// overloaded operator()), because the compiler would not be able to resolve
// the overload without knowing the argument types and the cv- and noexcept-
// qualifications. If you do know those already and can thus specify the
// overload to the compiler, you do not need this class. The only remaining
// piece of information is the result type, which you can get with
// std::invoke_result.

namespace detail
{
    template <std::size_t i, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_arg_impl
    {
        static_assert(i<sizeof...(Args), "Requested argument type out of bounds (function does not declare this many arguments)");

        using type = std::tuple_element_t<i, std::tuple<Args...>>;
    };

    template <typename R, typename C, bool IsVariadic, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_class
    {
        static constexpr std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);
        static constexpr auto is_variadic = IsVariadic;

        using result_type = R;
        using class_type = C;

        template <std::size_t i>
        using arg = invocable_traits_arg_impl<i,Args...>::type;
    };

    template <typename R, bool IsVariadic, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_free : public invocable_traits_class<R, void, IsVariadic, Args...> {};
}

template <typename T>
struct invocable_traits;

#define INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(cv,...)                                               \
/* handle functions, with all possible iterations of reference and noexcept */      \
template <typename R, typename... Args>                                             \
struct invocable_traits<R(Args... __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv>                    \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_free<R,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};          \
template <typename R, typename... Args>                                             \
struct invocable_traits<R(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv &>                   \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_free<R,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};          \
template <typename R, typename... Args>                                             \
struct invocable_traits<R(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv &&>                  \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_free<R,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};          \
template <typename R, typename... Args>                                             \
struct invocable_traits<R(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv noexcept>            \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_free<R,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};          \
template <typename R, typename... Args>                                             \
struct invocable_traits<R(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv & noexcept>          \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_free<R,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};          \
template <typename R, typename... Args>                                             \
struct invocable_traits<R(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv && noexcept>         \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_free<R,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};          \
/* handle pointers to member functions (incl. iterations of reference and noexcept) */\
template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>                                 \
struct invocable_traits<R(C::*)(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv>               \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_class<R,C,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};       \
template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>                                 \
struct invocable_traits<R(C::*)(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv &>             \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_class<R,C,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};       \
template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>                                 \
struct invocable_traits<R(C::*)(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv &&>            \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_class<R,C,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};       \
template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>                                 \
struct invocable_traits<R(C::*)(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv noexcept>      \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_class<R,C,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};       \
template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>                                 \
struct invocable_traits<R(C::*)(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv & noexcept>    \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_class<R,C,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};       \
template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>                                 \
struct invocable_traits<R(C::*)(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv && noexcept>   \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_class<R,C,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};       \
/* handle pointers to data members */                                               \
__VA_OPT__( /* no variadic function version for data members, (inverted) skip */    \
template <typename C, typename R>                                                   \
struct invocable_traits<R C::* cv>                                                  \
    : public detail::invocable_traits_class<R,C,false> {};                          \
) /* end __VA_OPT___*/

// cover all const and volatile permutations
INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(, )
INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(const, )
INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(volatile, )
INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(const volatile, )
// and also variadic function versions
INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(, ...)
INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(const, ...)
INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(volatile, ...)
INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(const volatile, ...)
#undef INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC

// pointers to functions
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct invocable_traits<R(*)(Args...)>                  : public invocable_traits<R(Args...)> {};
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct invocable_traits<R(*)(Args...) noexcept>         : public invocable_traits<R(Args...)> {};
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct invocable_traits<R(*)(Args..., ...)>             : public invocable_traits<R(Args..., ...)> {};
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct invocable_traits<R(*)(Args..., ...) noexcept>    : public invocable_traits<R(Args..., ...)> {};
// references to functions
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct invocable_traits<R(&)(Args...)>                  : public invocable_traits<R(Args...)> {};
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct invocable_traits<R(&)(Args...) noexcept>         : public invocable_traits<R(Args...)> {};
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct invocable_traits<R(&)(Args..., ...)>             : public invocable_traits<R(Args..., ...)> {};
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct invocable_traits<R(&)(Args..., ...) noexcept>    : public invocable_traits<R(Args..., ...)> {};

// get at operator() of any struct/class defining it (this includes lambdas)
// bit of machinery for better error messages
namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    concept HasCallOperator = requires(T)
    {
        std::declval<T>().operator();
    };

    template <typename T, bool isCallable>
    struct invocable_traits_extract : invocable_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

    template <typename T>
    struct invocable_traits_extract<T, false>
    {
        static_assert(std::is_class_v<T>, "passed type is not a class, and thus cannot have an operator()");
        static_assert(!std::is_class_v<T> || HasCallOperator<T>, "passed type is a class that doesn't have an operator()");
        
        // to reduce excessive compiler error output
        static constexpr std::size_t arity = 0;
        static constexpr auto is_variadic = false;
        using result_type = void;
        using class_type = void;
        template <size_t i> struct arg { using type = void; };
    };
}

template <typename T>
struct invocable_traits : detail::invocable_traits_extract<std::decay_t<T>, detail::HasCallOperator<T>> {};
```

testing code:

```
#include <string>

void test(int)
{}
void test2(int) noexcept
{}
void testEllipsis(int,...)
{}

struct tester
{
    void yolo(char)
    {}
    void yoloEllipsis(char, ...)
    {}
    static long yoloStatic(short)
    {}

    void operator()(int in_)
    {}

    std::string field;
};


int main()
{
    auto lamb = [](const int& in_) {return "ret"; };

    using traits = invocable_traits<decltype(lamb)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, traits::arg<0>>, "");


    using traits2 = invocable_traits<decltype(&test)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits2b = invocable_traits<decltype(&test2)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2b::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2b::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(!traits2b::is_variadic, "");

    using traits2c = invocable_traits<decltype(&testEllipsis)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2c::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2c::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(traits2c::is_variadic, "");

    using traits3 = invocable_traits<decltype(&tester::yolo)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits3::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, traits3::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits3b = invocable_traits<decltype(&tester::yoloEllipsis)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits3b::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<tester, traits3b::class_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, traits3b::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(traits3b::is_variadic, "");

    using traits3c = invocable_traits<decltype(&tester::yoloStatic)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<long, traits3c::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits3c::class_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<short, traits3c::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(!traits3c::is_variadic, "");

    using traits4 = invocable_traits<decltype(&tester::field)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::string, traits4::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(traits4::arity==0, "");


    using traits5 = invocable_traits<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(lamb)>>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits5::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, traits5::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits6 = invocable_traits<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<decltype(lamb)>>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits6::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lamb), traits6::class_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, traits6::arg<0>>, "");

    auto lamb2 = [](const int& in_, ...) mutable noexcept {return "ret"; };

    // functor
    using traits7 = invocable_traits<tester>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits7::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits7::arg<0>>, "");


    using traits8 = invocable_traits<decltype(lamb2)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits8::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, traits8::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(traits8::is_variadic, "");

    /*using traits9 = invocable_traits<int>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits9::result_type>, "");*/
    
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to `#undef` the macro after the use of it.  It's for expanding inside the header, not for the user to call.

What does it do with overloaded functions?

Comment: Thanks! Since its a small comment, i edited the code and added the #undef. Also improved compiler errors a bit.

Comment: If you try to instatiate invocable_traits on an overloaded function, MSVC gives me `incorrect argument to 'decltype'`, and intellisense: `cannot determine which instance of overloaded function is intended`. IOW, doesn't compile.