# invocable_traits v3

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++20

Update: there is a new version of this code: [v4 is posted here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272747/invocable-traits-v4)

---

Goal: implement traits that for anything callable return its arity, return type and the argument types. Since pointers to data members are also callable, those should be handled (and be considered 0-arity).

Code below, [try here](https://godbolt.org/z/TKErcTnaY). This is v3 ([v2 here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272668/invocable-traits)), incorporating a comment received on v2 and further enhancements i hit upon myself. In particular, v2 wasn't able to handle cv-qualification of the pointers themselves, e.g. "void (tester::*const)(char) const" didn't compile, but "void (tester::*)(char) const" did.

Did i cover all possible callables out there now?

```
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// inspired by https://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/traits.hpp
// and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28213747
// This does not handle overloaded functions (which includes functors with
// overloaded operator()), because the compiler would not be able to resolve
// the overload without knowing the argument types and the cv- and noexcept-
// qualifications. If you do know those already and can thus specify the
// overload to the compiler, you do not need this class. The only remaining
// piece of information is the result type, which you can get with
// std::invoke_result.

namespace detail
{
    template <std::size_t i, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_arg_impl
    {
        static_assert(i < sizeof...(Args), "Requested argument type out of bounds (function does not declare this many arguments)");

        using type = std::tuple_element_t<i, std::tuple<Args...>>;
    };

    template <typename R, typename C, bool IsVariadic, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_class
    {
        static constexpr std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);
        static constexpr auto is_variadic = IsVariadic;

        using result_type = R;
        using class_type = C;

        template <std::size_t i>
        using arg = typename invocable_traits_arg_impl<i, Args...>::type;
    };

    template <typename R, bool IsVariadic, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_free : public invocable_traits_class<R, void, IsVariadic, Args...> {};


    template <typename T>
    struct invocable_traits_impl;

    #define INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(cv,...)                                               \
    /* functions, including noexcept versions */                                        \
    template <typename R, typename... Args>                                             \
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R(Args... __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv>               \
        : public invocable_traits_free<R,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};                  \
    template <typename R, typename... Args>                                             \
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv noexcept>       \
        : public invocable_traits_free<R,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};                  \
    /* pointers to member functions (incl. noexcept versions) */                        \
    template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>                                 \
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R(C::*)(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv>          \
        : public invocable_traits_class<R,C,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};               \
    template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args>                                 \
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R(C::*)(Args...__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__) cv noexcept> \
        : public invocable_traits_class<R,C,0 __VA_OPT__(+1),Args...> {};

    // cover all const and volatile permutations
    INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(, )
    INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(const, )
    INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(volatile, )
    INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(const volatile, )
    // and also variadic function versions
    INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(, ...)
    INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(const, ...)
    INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(volatile, ...)
    INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC(const volatile, ...)
    #undef INVOCABLE_TRAITS_SPEC

    /* pointers to data members */
    template <typename C, typename R>
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R C::*>
        : public invocable_traits_class<R,C,false> {};

    // pointers to functions
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R(*)(Args...)>                 : public invocable_traits_impl<R(Args...)> {};
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R(*)(Args...) noexcept>        : public invocable_traits_impl<R(Args...)> {};
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R(*)(Args..., ...)>            : public invocable_traits_impl<R(Args..., ...)> {};
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    struct invocable_traits_impl<R(*)(Args..., ...) noexcept>   : public invocable_traits_impl<R(Args..., ...)> {};


    // get at operator() of any struct/class defining it (this includes lambdas)
    // bit of machinery for better error messages
    template <typename T>
    concept HasCallOperator = requires(T t)
    {
        t.operator();
    };

    template <typename T, bool isCallable>
    struct invocable_traits_extract : invocable_traits_impl<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

    template <typename T>
    struct invocable_traits_extract<T, false>
    {
        static_assert(std::is_class_v<T>, "passed type is not a class, and thus cannot have an operator()");
        static_assert(!std::is_class_v<T> || HasCallOperator<T>, "passed type is a class that doesn't have an operator()");

        // to reduce excessive compiler error output
        static constexpr std::size_t arity = 0;
        static constexpr auto is_variadic = false;
        using result_type = void;
        using class_type = void;
        template <size_t i> struct arg { using type = void; };
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct invocable_traits_impl : invocable_traits_extract<T, HasCallOperator<T>> {};
}

template <typename T>
struct invocable_traits : detail::invocable_traits_impl<std::decay_t<T>> {};
```

testing code:

```
#include <string>

void test(int)
{}
void test2(int) noexcept
{}
void testEllipsis(int,...)
{}

struct tester
{
    void yolo(char) const
    {}
    void yoloEllipsis(char, ...)
    {}
    static long yoloStatic(short)
    {}

    void operator()(int in_)
    {}

    const std::string field;
};


int main()
{
    auto lamb = [](const int& in_) {return "ret"; };

    using traits = invocable_traits<decltype(lamb)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lamb), traits::class_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, traits::arg<0>>, "");


    using traits2 = invocable_traits<decltype(&test)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits2b = invocable_traits<decltype(&test2)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2b::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2b::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(!traits2b::is_variadic, "");

    using traits2c = invocable_traits<decltype(&testEllipsis)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2c::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2c::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(traits2c::is_variadic, "");

    auto& fref = test;
    using traits2d = invocable_traits<decltype(fref)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2d::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2d::arg<0>>, "");

    void (*farr[3])(int) = { &test };
    using traits2e = invocable_traits<decltype(farr[0])>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2e::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2e::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits2f = invocable_traits<decltype(test)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2f::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2f::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits2g = invocable_traits<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(test)>>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits2g::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits2g::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits3 = invocable_traits<decltype(&tester::yolo)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits3::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, traits3::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits3b = invocable_traits<decltype(&tester::yoloEllipsis)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits3b::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<tester, traits3b::class_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, traits3b::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(traits3b::is_variadic, "");

    using traits3c = invocable_traits<const volatile decltype(&tester::yoloEllipsis)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits3c::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<tester, traits3c::class_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, traits3c::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(traits3c::is_variadic, "");

    using traits3d = invocable_traits<decltype(&tester::yoloStatic)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<long, traits3d::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits3d::class_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<short, traits3d::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(!traits3d::is_variadic, "");

    using traits4 = invocable_traits<const decltype(&tester::field)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const std::string, traits4::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(traits4::arity==0, "");


    using traits5 = invocable_traits<std::add_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(lamb)>>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits5::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, traits5::arg<0>>, "");

    using traits6 = invocable_traits<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<decltype(lamb)>>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits6::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(lamb), traits6::class_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, traits6::arg<0>>, "");

    auto lamb2 = [](const int& in_, ...) mutable noexcept {return "ret"; };

    // functor
    using traits7 = invocable_traits<tester>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<void, traits7::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, traits7::arg<0>>, "");


    using traits8 = invocable_traits<decltype(lamb2)>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits8::result_type>, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const int&, traits8::arg<0>>, "");
    static_assert(traits8::is_variadic, "");

    /*using traits9 = invocable_traits<int>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<const char*, traits9::result_type>, "");*/
    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you remove `this` qualifier (`R (C::*)(Args...) /*&*//**&&*/`).

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks absolutely. Thanks for both comments. I also don't need the cv-qualified versions for pointers to data members, so can take those out of the MACRO. I have updated the code since these are minor change and there haven't been significant comment yet.